# how to apply lighting to .obj file on pyopengl

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

i implement arcball with an object from .obj file in the center
when i try to implement lighting, the object show strange behaviour

[image: initial state]

when i turn the object slightly, the object deconstruct and suddenly show the back side

[image: object deconstruct]

[image: show back side]

this behaviour doesn's come up until i implement lighting
based on this [How to correctly add a light to make object get a better view with pygame and pyopengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56514791/how-to-correctly-add-a-light-to-make-object-get-a-better-view-with-pygame-and-py)

this is what i do regarding the lighting impelementation

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    display = (SCREEN_WIDTH,SCREEN_HEIGHT)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 30000.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -250)

    glLight(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,  (1, 1, 1, 0)) 
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, (0, 0, 0, 1))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (2, 2, 2, 1))
    
    while True:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW )
        glLoadIdentity()

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
        glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)
        glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE )

        object1.draw()

        glDisable(GL_LIGHT0)
        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
        glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test). Enable the depth test before the application loop:

```py
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
```